# Formal demonstration of $\left|\thinspace\sin{\frac{1}{x}}\right|\leq 1;\thinspace x≠0$

Tags: trigonometry

Is there any mathematical demonstration of the fact: $$\left|\thinspace\sin{\frac{1}{x}}\right|\leq 1;\thinspace x≠0$$

Intuitively, I can justify the expression, but I was hoping if I could fetch a more formal definition.

Comment: By the definition of the sine function is holds that $sin(x) \in [-1,1]$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

And well, $\frac{1}{x}$ is in $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT.- For all $x\ne0$ one has $1/x=y\in\mathbb R$ and it is well known that $|\sin(y)|\le1$

Comment: Sometimes, I post questions without thinking. :|

Comment: It is normal in math learning. Ahead!